# npm i firebase --save npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve (firebase not installing in VS Code)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, npm, backend

I am working on a react app.I wanted to connect it to google firebase.For that I created a firebase.js file in src folder present in instagram-clone folder.But when I am running the command npm i firebase ,I am getting so many errors.Also tried npm i firebase --save command but that also doesnt seem to work.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]. Also sharing the firebase.js file code
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How should i solve this error??
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/636kM.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM5OK.png